# Multiple Objects Returned (Profiles) while creating Account on Mezzanine Project

Tags: python, django, profiles

I've got a working mezzanine (with pybb) setup in my local environment. The pybb got an abstract Profile class to define some user attributes and also ships a Profile class in case you're not using one already.

Everything is working except the signup process which ends up in creating a user, but resulting in the following traceback:

http://pastebin.com/MFuBpc2A

I thought the pybbMiddleware could be the issue. (How am I creating 2 profiles?)

```
class PybbMiddleware(object):
     def process_request(self, request):
         if request.user.is_authenticated():
             try:
                # Here we try to load profile, but can get error
                # if user created during syncdb but profile model
                # under south control. (Like pybb.Profile).
                profile = request.user.get_profile()
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                # Ok, we should create new profile for this user
                # and grant permissions for add posts
                user_saved(request.user, created=True)
                profile = request.user.get_profile()

            language = translation.get_language_from_request(request)

            if not profile.language:
                profile.language = language
                profile.save()

            if profile.language and profile.language != language:
                request.session['django_language'] = profile.language
                translation.activate(profile.language)
                request.LANGUAGE_CODE = translation.get_language()
```

The user_saved() in pybb's signals.py:

```
def user_saved(instance, created, **kwargs):
    if not created:
        return
    try:
        add_post_permission = Permission.objects.get_by_natural_key('add_post', 'pybb', 'post')
        add_topic_permission = Permission.objects.get_by_natural_key('add_topic', 'pybb', 'topic')
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return
    instance.user_permissions.add(add_post_permission, add_topic_permission)
    instance.save()
    if settings.AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE == 'pybb.Profile':
        from models import Profile
        Profile(user=instance).save()
```

and on top of that I've got another user_saved() in accounts/models.py:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def user_saved(sender=None, instance=None, **kwargs):
    Profile.objects.get_or_create(**{str(user_field): instance})
```

Is it calling both and thus creating 2 profiles?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are using mezzanine.accounts and have AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE set in settings.py. The code in mezzanine.accounts.models sets up a signal so that when the User model is saved a Profile is generated. I'm actually running into the same issue when creating a User and Profile in using tastypie.